# Python Deleting Certain File Extensions

Tags: python, logic, file-extension, delete-file

I'm fairly new to Python, but I have gotten this code to work, and in fact, do what it's intended to do.

However, I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to code this, perhaps to enhance the processing speed.

```
 import os, glob


def scandirs(path):
    for currentFile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*') ):
        if os.path.isdir(currentFile):
            print 'got a directory: ' + currentFile
            scandirs(currentFile)
        print "processing file: " + currentFile
        png = "png";
        jpg = "jpg";
        if currentFile.endswith(png) or currentFile.endswith(jpg):
            os.remove(currentFile)

scandirs('C:\Program Files (x86)\music\Songs')
```

Right now, there are about 8000 files, and it takes quite some time to process every file and check if it indeed ends in png or jpg.

Comment: You probably want to check out [`os.path.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.walk).

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to use that.

Answer (score 20):

Since you are recursing through subdirectories, use [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
import os

def scandirs(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for currentFile in files:
            print "processing file: " + currentFile
            exts = ('.png', '.jpg')
            if currentFile.lower().endswith(exts):
                os.remove(os.path.join(root, currentFile))
```

Comment: If you change `exts=('.png', '.jpg')` to `exts=['.png', '.jpg']`, the code will work for only 1 extension as well.

Comment: I thought that performing a 3rd for loop at the end would be slower than using the `os.path.splitext()` method and doing a compare, but I timed it and this is the fastest solution.

Comment: you can use `currentFile.endswith(exts)` now (`endswith` accepts a `tuple`).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Thanks for the improvement.

Answer (score 2):

If the program works and the speed is acceptable, I wouldn't change it.

Otherwise, you could try unutbu's answer.

Generally, I would leave away the

```
png = "png"
jpg = "jpg"
```

stuff as I don't see any purpose in not using the strings directly.

And better test for ".png" instead of "png".

An even better solution would be to define

```
extensions = ('.png', '.jpg')
```

somewhere centrally and use that in

```
if any(currentFile.endswith(ext) for ext in extensions):
    os.remove(currentFile)
```

.